# Serenity BDD and RabbitMQ use together

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework, rabbitmq, serenity-bdd

**Details**

Currently we are in the process of integrating RabbitMQ into our stages. I sell here accordingly a test plan through.

Currently we use the test framework Serenity and here also for the Api approach corresponding solutions from Serenity.

But can I test RabbitMQ messages in Serenity?
Does RabbitMQ also offer corresponding integrations or are the functionalities from Serenity sufficient?

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anything exists out of the box. You will probably need to write some steps that use a RabbitMQ client (amqp-client) to check if there are events on the queue etc...